# customize: POST output in jqGrid without changing source file?

Tags: session, jquery, jqgrid, modx

I'm trying to turn jqGrid within MODx, as do other data exchange using "$. ajax", move the call from a URL to a resource protected by a password and from there call a snippet of code in PHP, so the security framework, the ajax call is guaranteed

This is one example of a chunk $.ajax:

```
      $.ajax ({
                url :'[[~94]]',
                type: 'post',
                async: false,
                success: function(rsp) {
                                $.Cookie("xxxxxx-tipodirlist", rsp);
                          }

             });
```

*[[~94]] is a protected resource is within a snippet call [[!SnpBridgedata_blabla]]

the system works perfectly well throughout the web application, receiving and sending data safely and securely.

Now a customer asked me for a completed application wanted web results in a good grid and after seeing a bit of code I decided to use jqGrid for my project.
integration was quick and I am very happy to have changed "DataTable" with "jqGrid," but when I finished the test, change the absolute path to xxxxxx.php with the call to snippet

this is the code for jqGrid:

```
  chargeSedi function (idx)
  {
    // Test with file. Php !work fine!
    // Var esURL = 'http://xxxxx.com/xxxxxxx.php?IDX =' + idx;
    // Test with MODx resource  !not work!
    esURL var = '[[~ 97]] & IDX =' + idx;
    csURL var = '[[~ 96]] & IDX =' + idx;
    tipodirlist = $ var. cookie ("xxxxxxxx-tipodirlist");
    tiposedelist = $ var. cookie ("xxxxxxx-tiposedelist");


  $("#sediTable").ready(function() { 
      $("#sediTable").jqGrid({ 
              url:csURL, 
              datatype: "json",
              height: 250, 
              autowidth:true,
              colNames:[ 'ID','CODICE', 'NOME','TDIR', 'DIR','COMUNE', 'PROVINCIA','CAP', 'TSEDE','NOTA'], 
              colModel:[ 

 {name:'ID',index:'ID', width:25, editable: false}, 
 {name:'CODICE',index:'CODICE', width:60, editable: true}, 
 {name:'NOME',index:'NOME', width:60, editable: true}, 
 {name:'TDIR',index:'TDIR', width:60, editable: true,edittype:"select",editoptions:{value:tipodirlist}},         
 {name:'DIR',index:'DIR', width:200, sortable:false,editable: true},
 {name:'COMUNE',index:'COMUNE', width:170, sortable:false,editable: true},
 {name:'PROVINCIA',index:'PROVINCIA', width:170, sortable:false,editable: true},
 {name:'CAP',index:'CAP', width:40, sortable:false,editable: true},
 {name:'TSEDE',index:'TSEDE', width:90, editable: true,edittype:"select",editoptions:{value:tiposedelist}},       
 {name:'NOTA',index:'NOTA', width:170, sortable:false,editable: true,edittype:"textarea", editoptions:{rows:"2",cols:"10"}} ], 

      sortname: 'ID', 
      viewrecords: true, 
      sortorder: "desc", 
      loadonce: true,
      editurl: esURL , 
      caption: "Sedi" }); 

});
```

]

and for my surprise the MODx deny Access to jqGrid ajax calls, as if you were out of session, but after hours testing and watching the traffic with wireshark I realized that jqGrid sends a POST variable called "id" and call MODx a GET variable "id". this in other environments is possible without problem, but it is not possible MODx and there's the problem.

my question is how I can change the name of the POST variable "id" jqGrid, without changing the source of jqGrid?

at the same time wanted to ask, you can customize the import of a select the value and not the index

example of trame POST:

```
            {Name: 'TDIR', index: 'TDIR', width: 60, editable: true, EditType: "select" editoptions: {value: tipodirlist}}
```

tipodirlist = 1:via;2:piazza;3:ect

TDIR=2

```
   CODICE=1&NOME=principale&TDIR=2&DIR=Roma&COMUNE=Torino&PROVINCIA=Torino&CAP=10000&TSEDE=2&NOTA=NO=edit&id=0
```

for this:

TDIR=piazza

```
   CODICE=1&NOME=principale&TDIR=piazza&DIR=Roma&COMUNE=Torino&PROVINCIA=Torino&CAP=10000&TSEDE=2&NOTA=NO=edit&id=0
```

without having to filter the results on the server.

---

I hope I've explained well and clear. as I asked myself, the team "StackOverflow" before asking this question

Thank you so much
Regards

niro.

PS.I hope that GOD "Oleg" help me:)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know and don't use MODx. Nevertheless I hope that your problem is: how to rename the name of the `id` parameter to have no conflict with the `id` parameter used by MODx.

If I understand your question correct you should just add additional [prmNames](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions) parameter which set the new name of `id` parameter used in editing operations:

```
prmNames: {id: 'myId'}
```

The example will rename the default `id` parameter name (`{id: "id"}`) to `myId` which you should you in your server part.